# Is it possible to create a new book from the rows found under a "Find All" search?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

The way I do it now is:

1. CTRL + F
2. Enter Data to Find (e.g. "57011-141")
3. Click Find All
4. Usually 10-20 rows will come up.  I then go one by one copying and pasting into a new book.

I am looking to automate this process as it is time consuming and error prone.

Comment: Why not add helper column with [FIND](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx) and filter results, then copy&paste to new sheet?

Comment: Sounds promising. Let me look into it.

Comment: The within_text parameter would be the column?

Comment: Here are the contents of cell B15:  "ARIA 4X6 1222-109 IVORY/BLACK"  I entered the function =FIND(A, B15) and a #NAME? error is returned. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `=FIND("A", B15)`

Comment: Ahh, yes that does work.  If you would like to put that as an answer I will give you a +1 for that!  However, Sean Cheshire's answer seems easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `57011-141` appears in a single column (sorting irrelevant)

Filter the data (This image is from Excel 2010)
[image: Filter menu in 2010]
The down arrow next to the column name will allow you to set the filter under TextFilters -> Contains
Once the filter is applied, select all the displayed data - use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>
Copy the data (use menu or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
Find your destination and paste (use menu or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
This will copy column headers, as well as the filtered data, so if you have multiple copies to do, you will have to remove the extra headers

Comment: Yes, the simplest answer. And can be applied to many more things. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If `57011-141` appears in single column, here is the solution.

1. Sort the book with that particular column.
2. CTRL + F
3. Data to Find (e.g. "57011-141")
4. Click Find All
5. Cntrl + A
6. Close Find & Replace Dialog
7. Shift + Space to select all rows which returned by Find
8. Copy and paste into new sheet

Edit:

if "57011-141" found in middle of a string in cell,

1. Add a new column (D) next to the search column (C)
2. Formula in column D1 `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("57011-141",C1,1))`
3. Copy & Paste the formula to all rows
4. Sort column D

Now you will get all the identified rows in column D if value `TRUE`

Comment: I appreciate your response!  I don't know if it matters, but the data "57011-141" only appears in one column but it is only part of a string stored in that column.  So I don't think it can be sorted. Is there another way?

Comment: Sounds promising as well.  For me, the search column is (B) and I added column (C). So I copy and pasted this text into C1 block:  " =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("57011-141",C1,1))" but how to do I copy and paste the formula into all rows?

Comment: Oh I think I got it, I changed it from C to B, obviously.

Comment: Check @Sean Cheshire answers too. That one is easiest than my answer

Comment: Yes, I did, I do appreciate your help as your way did work as well!